# Where is my margin gone?

Tags: support, design, mobile-web

Please compare the following two screenshots. The first one is made is made on stackoverflow, the second here, using my Android in full site mode.

> [image]

The striking difference is the margin on the left side of the question body:

> [image]

This margin makes voting on mobile much easier, because I don't have to hit the outermost possible place on the screen.

Could I pretty please have them back?

Comment: On a sidenote... I have no idea how these pictures look on a large screen.. edits imroving their appearance are welcomed

Comment: I notice it too, but I'm on a desktop machine. The "margin" is still there on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the issue is that they changed the width of one of the elements, making it look weird on small screens. For example, <= 1024px, the "margin" disappears. The relevant style is:

```
#content {
   /* ... */
    margin: 0px auto;
   /* ... */
    width: 1000px;
}
```

I changed it from `1000px` to `980px` and it looks normal again.